# Using TIKA and POI in the same project without getting into version issues?

Tags: java, classpath, apache-poi, dependency-management, apache-tika

I've got a requirement to generate reports as xls-sheets, but I already have TIKA in my project. Now TIKA does *include* POI, what worries me here is that TIKA 1.2 (which I'm using currently) includes a beta build of POI 3.8.

I foresee the day when I have to update either POI or TIKA due to a bugfix, while keeping the other one as is. Does anyone have experience with this situation? Is it an issue in reality or should I just go with the POI version that comes with TIKA?

If I want/need to keep them separate, are there accepted practices how to manage this (I guess there is no way around whacking my own ClassLoader to do this?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, just go with the latest versions of both. Tika upgrades its POI dependency whenever there's a new version out, for bug fixes and new features.

If you need to run a newer version of POI than Tika supports, then you should check Tika out from SVN. There are normally fixes in there for the newer version, and if not they'll be posted to the Tika JIRA.

Comment: Hm, since there aren't awefully many responses, I trust that it isn't a problem in practice and will happily go with the POI that comes with TIKA as you recommend.

Comment: That's what [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) largely does, and works fine there!

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to use Tika 2.2.1 and POI 5.2.2 together and it kept failing with "unknown class" errors.  I didn't realize that Tika used POI, so I simply removed the POI classes from my project and it's working now.  I'm lucky that I don't have to do anything fancy with POI so *I* don't care exactly which version of POI is used.